# How set up PAC(proxy autoconfiguration script) using windows 10 API

Tags: c++, powershell, api, windows-10

There is a way to playing with some advance setting in windows 10 using API? I would like setting up proxy auto configuration script, but i want do that using script **no GUI**, is it even possible??:). I would like use C++, but the Windows API is like enigma for me.

I found something like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpgetproxyforurl. But i think it is not what i need

Thanks for all of you answer

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't using C++ or an API, this PowerShell command should work...

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' -Name 'AutoConfigURL' -Value 'http://proxy/script.pac'
```

Hope this helps, nonetheless.